# How can you measure how much a feature spend in each state in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to the cycle time of my features for each state they spend on.
I am using the cycle time widget but this doesn't show the time for each state and it doesn't go beyond 180 days.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a report in PowerBi, which can calculate time-in-state. The time that a work item spent in a specific state can now be calculated by summing the *Date Diff* in Days for each work item. This calculation will include all of the time spent in a specific state even if it has switched between states multiple times.

```
State Time in Days = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'View Name'[Date Diff in Days] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'View Name', 'View Name'[Work Item Id] ),
    'View Name'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'View Name'[Date] ),
    'View Name'[State] = EARLIER ( 'View Name'[State] )
) + 0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-timeinstate-report?view=azure-devops#add-is-last-day-in-state

Comment: Hey, this is great but requires a Power BI pro account as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this extension for calculating the time that Work Items spent in the workflow at each state https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SaaSJet.tis-azure.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)